# THE PHP SESSION

Tags: php, session

I have a simple login system.
for example, localhost/login.php
Im using the session remember that whether the user logined before.I try to clear the firefox browser history and refresh the current page(administrator  panel page), the page will be forwarded to the login page.

I would like to know why I just clear the browser history and the session will also be deleted?
The session is stored in the server.

Comment: Have you cleared the history **including cookies**...?

Comment: Session will be delated just after shutting the browser. This is designed to do so. Use cookie or html localStorage for non important data.

Answer (score 4):

Yes session are stored on server. But a reference to that session(session_id) is stored at client side in cookie. When you clear browser history with cookies you loss reference id to your session store on server.

Answer (score 2):

That is because session usually rely on Cookies (stored in the client browser) to recognize the client and link it to the stored session. Once the history is deleted, the session still exists on the server, but isn't linked to the client anymore.

Sessions can also be set to use a GET variable in the URL in stead of a cookie. But that is usually considered a security risk, as users tend to sometimes send their URL to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

As seen on [function.session-id.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

Sessions use cookies to save the `session_id` value. So, when you clear the browser cache/cookies/history, it also clears the `session_id` and generates a new one!

Comment: Not 100% accurate. It clears the *cookie* which basically means the client doesn't have any handle on any session anymore.

Comment: Exactly, maybe I didn't explain it the right way, but I guess it's understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mahendra. The `$_SESSION[]` is stored on the server, but a reference is stored on the client side, thus when you clear the session, the client session does not have any value to compare the session against, so it also clears the server session.

Use `unset($_SESSION[])` to clear the specified session object